# Creating relativeLayout programmatically?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In my first attempt to create a `layout` programmatically, I created the below posted first-xml file and I want to append to it programmatically the below posted second-xml file.
I also referred to [this tutorial](http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/220-lesson-16-creating-layout-programmatically-layoutparams.html) but it seems that creating `linearlayout` and `relativelayout` programmatically are different. Also in my attempt to do create the `relativelayout` eclipse underscores my `layoutparams` with red squiggle, plus, i do not know whether the parameter was set first is the width or the height. Please advice and provide recommendations.

my attempts:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout_programmatically_00);

    RelativeLayout mRelLayout00 = new RelativeLayout(this);
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams mRelLayoutParams = new  
            LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            , android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

First-xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="match_parent">

      <LinearLayout 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">
      </LinearLayout>
```

second-xml"whta i want to achieve programmatically":

```
<RelativeLayout 
              android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal">
              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/menu"
                  android:textSize="@dimen/titlesTextSize"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                  android:shadowDx="0"
                  android:shadowDy="0"
                  android:shadowRadius="10"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
                  android:textColor="@color/titleColor">
              </TextView>    
          </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So you have 2 diff xml files and you want to add them both in a third layout programatically?

Comment: no, the posted "first-xml" is the one i have in the layout folder. the contents of the "second-xml" are those what i want to do programmatically.

Comment: ok. inflate second xml and add to the relativelayout. I will add code shortly

Comment: i do not want to use the inflater

Comment: then create it from scratch. However if you have a lot of views in the second xml you are better off using an inflater. That's what it is meant for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. I have not tested it. Let me know if you have any problems.

Define the styles like this

```
<style name="MyStyleText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">10</item>
  </style>
```

And in java file

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp ;
    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textLP ;
    textLP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);


TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText(getString(R.string.hello_world));
tv.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.MyStyleText);

rl.addView(tv, textLP);
this.addContentView(rl, lp);
```

Comment: can u please tell me, how to set both of the gravity and layoutGravity?

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

**activity_main.xml**

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private LinearLayout lnrMain;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lnrMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrMain);

        RelativeLayout mRelLayout00 = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mRelLayoutParams = new
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mRelLayout00.setLayoutParams(mRelLayoutParams);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textParams.setMargins(18,0,0,0);
        textView.setLayoutParams(textParams);
        textView.setTextSize(16);
        textView.setShadowLayer(10,0,0,android.R.color.white);
        textView.setText("menu");
        mRelLayout00.addView(textView);
        lnrMain.addView(mRelLayout00);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_linearlayout_in_first_xml);

View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.second_xml, null);

ll.addView(view);
```